# How to make multi-language on php?

Tags: php, arrays, multilingual

I want to perform multi-language of my site , but My code only work once and cannot work any more can anyone help me?

Main Site

```
    ...

    <?php if ($_SESSION['lang']=='hk'){
        include_once 'lang/lang.hk.php';
    }else {
        include_once 'lang/lang.en.php';
    }
    ?>

    ...
    <a href="redirect/hk.php">中文</a>
    ...


    <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo $lang['ABC']; ?></div>
```

redirect/hk.php

```
    <?php
    $_SESSION['lang']=='hk';
    header("location:http://example.com/");
    ?>
```

lang.hk.php

```
    $lang = array();

    $lang['ABC'] = 'XXXX';
```

lang.en.php

```
    $lang = array();

    $lang['ABC'] = 'Hello';
```

I click "hk.php" many times but the site still show "Hello" , But when I set that $lang="hk" manually , it works. How can I fix it ??

Comment: $_SESSION['lang']=='hk'; I think you messed up = with ==

Comment: And if the session was started (everywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Naruto and Fred -ii- are rights.

You have to put a session_start() at the top of your index.php and redirect/hk.php and modify this with :

```
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'hk';
```